# 'tensorflow_core.estimator' has no attribute 'inputs', why does this happen?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a neural network algorithm in a jupyter notebook.

```
input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=10,
    num_epochs=5,
    shuffle=True)
```

Produces this error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.estimator' has no attribute 'inputs'

I don't understand why this is happening. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: [Possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762759/how-to-fix-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-estimator-error).  Just a guess, but your environment is some how polluted with multiple/different versions of tensorflow and you are not calling the estimator api you think you are.

Answer (score 7):

in case you are running TF 2.00. You can check the version with

```
print(tf.__version__)
```

use [tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/inputs/pandas_input_fn) instead

Comment: Yes I was facing the same issue and I changed it to tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn  and it worked. Apparently the tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn is deprecated. And use tensorflow 1.0 instead of 2.0

Comment: Thanks, @dinnouti this has been really helpfull.

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
from tensorflow_core.estimator import inputs
```